# RadGrid data columns are out of alignment with the header columns. Any suggestions?

Tags: asp.net, webforms, telerik, radgrid

My Telerik RadGrid data columns are no longer aligned with the column headers. These Telerik ASP.Net Ajax (web forms) RadGrids used to look fine. Here is how they look now:

[image]

The issue corrects itself when I re-size a column. Also, the issue corrects itself if FrozenColumnCount >= 1 and I move the horizontal scroll bar. There have been no recent code changes but I have upgraded to Telerik.Web.UI v.2013.3.1114.40. This seems to be when the problem started. Can I use the upgrade wizard to downgrade to an older version? I'd rather not downgrade. Instead how can I programmatically resize the grid when it loads?

I'm using StackOverflow instead of Telerik support in hopes of getting a quick resolution to this problem.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Setting the MasterTableView Width to 100% makes the problem go away:

```
<MasterTableView DataKeyNames="ContactKey" CommandItemDisplay="Top" Width="100%">
```

As noted by Telerik support here: [RadGrid Column header and data item alignment problem](http://www.telerik.com/community/forums/aspnet-ajax/grid/radgrid-column-header-and-data-item-alignment-problem.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

Something else to note: If you set ClientIDMode to "Static", header alignments can fail to work when using static headers.

Answer (score -1):

Remove `UseStaticHeaders='True'`.

`RadGrid` frozen column properly not working.